# How to pass props to StyleSheet on custom view in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

So, I have a custom view. On that view, besides taking the children components, I also wanna take backgroundColor and some other StyleSheet property so I can style it depends on the screens.

This is the App.tsx.

```
export const MainScreen = ({}: Props) => {
  return (
    <CustomView backgroundColor={"#000"}>
      <Text>Example</Text>
    </CustomView>
  );
};
```

And this is the CustomView.tsx

```
type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  backgroundColor: string;
};

export const CustomView = ({ children, backgroundColor }: Props) => {
  return <View style={styles.container}>{children}</View>;
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```

Say, I wanna change the background color for this screen to #000 like on the codes above. But, I don't know how to handle the props on the CustomView so it can change the backgroundColor.

I tried writing this code

```
return <View style={styles.container, {backgroundColor: backgroundColor}}>{children}</View>;
```

But it overwrites the styles.container. On the other hand, if I write this

```
return <View style={{backgroundColor: backgroundColor}, styles.container}>{children}</View>;
```

It always throws the error that the left side of comma (the backgroundColor itself) is unused and has no side effects.

So, what should I do? How can I pass the props to handle the StyleSheet?

Comment: I assume you mean React Native instead of React?

Comment: @KevinAmiranoff Yes, that's what I mean. I should've specified React Native. I'm gonna edit the title & tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array to the `style` prop.

According to the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/style):

> The style prop can be a plain old JavaScript object. That's what we usually use for example code. You can also pass an array of styles - the last style in the array has precedence, so you can use this to inherit styles.

```
return <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: backgroundColor }]}>{children}</View>;
```

Comment: Wow, that's so simple. I forgot I had to use an array. Thanks!